# Flip an Imageview with two images back to back

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation, flip

I need to have a set of Image views on a Linear Layout. &

==> onClick of an ImageView, I want to **turn the Image to the back(Like Flipping Effect)** & show another Image.

==> Again on click of that Image or another Image, I want to apply the same effect for that Image View & the Previous Imageview must come to the default position.

---> I just checked the [FLIP ANIMATION](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) in Android. But it is flipping the total view.

**So I Just need How to flip an Image view in the same manner, with support from Android v2.2 & up**

I think it is quite complicated but it is interesting & need some help how to achieve this as I am just learning the Android(& Coding).

Thanks.!!!

Comment: Did you made the app as you desired, as I am also finding for the same functionality, Can you please help me for the same?

Comment: yes, but I moved to another technology... if you need I can re-check the logic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Well i think I had got the solution for the same. Thanks again anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this small library to do that :

https://github.com/castorflex/FlipImageView